# Password for mysql server

Tags: mysql

As I installed mysql the first time no password where given.Then I messed with the mysql shell and might have accidently set a password. So I couldn't remember it when I tried to use the server. Then I reinstalled the package but somehow it was still set and now I get these errors:

```
sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

and

```
 sudo mysql_secure_installation 
    
    Securing the MySQL server deployment.
    
    Enter password for user root: 
    Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: does `sudo -i && mysql` work?

Comment: No it doesnt work still
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: The `root` MySQL account should only be used when first setting up the server, or when fixing something that has gone really, really wrong. If you’ve set/changed the password and cannot remember it, the you’ll need to wipe the DB server off the machine, clearing remaining directories, and start again. If you need an admin account, create one that isn’t `root` but has the same permissions 